# Problema Codificación IronPython VS2017

Tags: python, visual-studio, utf-8

Buenas tardes. No he logrado que la consola interactiva de IronPython de Visual Studio 2017 lea e imprima correctamente los caracteres como "´"(tilde) o "ñ", y me esta afectando al momento de trabajar con paths donde algunas carpetas tienen estos caracteres.

Pantallazo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso Geany también, y ahí no tengo ningún problema con los caracteres. 
Quiero usar IronPython en VS para aprovechar los Office.Interop. 
Gracias!

Comment: Asegúrate de usar la declaración de la codificación del archivo al inicio de este, en python2.7 se suele colocar `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` en la primera linea del archivo

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta German Alzate. Sin embargo sigue sin funcionar... Actualizo la imagen.